# Apostrophes and optional argument (?) in grep vs agrep

Tags: r, regex, agrep

When I run the below 4 lines of code I dont get the same result from all 4.
Why is the last line not finding a match?

```
grep("CPA's", c("CPA's"))
agrep("CPA's", c("CPA's"))

grep("CPA'?s?", c("CPA's"))
agrep("CPA'?s?", c("CPA's"))
```

I haven't yet done my full reading on the fuzzy matching functions, but on the face of it I don't see why this would be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Because the difference is more than the default `max.distance` which is 0.1. Increase the `max.distance` and it will capture it.

```
agrep("CPA'?s?", "CPA's", max.distance = 0.15)
#[1] 1
```

To treat pattern as regular expression, select `fixed = FALSE` which will then work directly

```
agrep("CPA'?s?", "CPA's", fixed = FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. I didn't realize the default for the fixed argument to agrep was true. I thought agrep would take that as a regular expression and treat the two strings then as matches with no difference.

Comment: yes, you can also use `agrep("CPA'?s?", c("CPA's"), fixed = FALSE)` in which case it would be treated as regular expression.